# How to share desktop to an additional monitor

Tags: external-monitor

How to share desktop to an additional monitor?

I tried , but it looks not good. The external monitor resolution is as same as my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the dual monitor from the Ubuntu display preferences as explained below.

Open **Displays** which will display the following window.

[image: Screen settings]

Make sure following are taken care in this window:

1. If you see only one monitor, click on Detect Monitor, which should detect all the monitors connected to the Ubuntu laptop or desktop.
2. Uncheck Mirror Screens check-box as shown above. When you have this enabled, both the monitors will show the same display, which you don’t want.
3. Highlight the first monitor and click the ‘On’ radio button. The first monitor will already be in on state.
4. Highlight the second monitor and click the ‘On’ radio button.
5. Select the Show displays in panel check-box, which will display the icon to configure the display on the top right hand panel for easy access.
6. To change the display order of the monitors, simply drag the monitor to re-arrange them accordingly

Source: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/08/ubuntu-tips-how-to-setup-dual-monitor/